# Interfacing with TomTom device (Display devices screen on computer)

Tags: c#, navigation, gps, tomtom

Just a quick one, if anyone knows:

Is it possible to display a TomTom devices screen on a computer (so I can interface with it's navigation ability?)

They have an SDK, however that does not have any useful information on this question, but TomTom Home can do it - so can I? C# / C++ / Whatever.

Cheers

Comment: What are you trying to do? What ability do you want to interface to?

Comment: Attempting to use it's navigational ability through, say, a car computer. TomTom home has an emulator, but it turns the GPS to demo mode.

Comment: HOME is running its own copy of TomTom NavCore, which misses essential parts such as GPS software (as there's generally no GPS hardware on your PC either). Also, that NavCore emulator is loaded within the HOME process so and makes assumptions about its hosting process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TomTom is running linux so you can get the raw image data from /dev/raw.

```
cat /dev/fb > /mnt/sdcard/screenshot.raw
```

on the device should do it

Then you need to transfer it to your computer (needs to be done quickly).
This should be possible to do over Bluetooth, over USB or possibly by using a [Eye-Fi SD card](http://uk.eye.fi/).

I don't think it is possible to do it any other way.

[Access the device by Bluetooth console](http://opentom.org/BTconsole)